# Usefulness of integral operator as generalization of a matrix? (Intuition)

Tags: self-study, regularization, functional-data-analysis

In [this paper](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/ms/regtutorial.pdf) by Neumaier, page 5, he says

> [This problem] can be posed as the problem of solving the linear system $Ax=b$ where $A$ is the integral operator defined by 
>   \begin{equation}
> Ax(t) := \int_0^t x(\tau) d\tau 
> \end{equation}

Beyond recognition that both matrix and (Hilbert-Schmidt) integral operators are linear operators I had not considered the usefulness of the relationship, though now that I'm looking around I suppose that this is the fundamental relationship in Karhunen-Loeve theorem (functional analog to PCA), Mercer's theorem (pivotal for characterizing kernel in the so-called *kernel* trick), and several others that we here find useful. It is for this reason that I am asking my question here rather than math stack exchange, though I am certain that they would provide a technically equivalent answer. I think that having an intuitive explanation and example of the two will be useful for people coming to cross validated with interest in more theoretical statistics and probability questions who do not have a strong background in functional analysis.

To be specific: beyond the technical equivalence as linear operators on Hilbert Spaces I am interested in an intuitive explanation of the relationship between matrix and integral operators. In particular, I am having difficulty constructing a simple example that *shows* what the functional analysis *proves*.

---

As an aside, I had difficulty with the tags. I chose regularization because that is the topic of the paper that motivated the question, and of course self-study. I chose functional data analysis since this is of fundamental importance if we are looking in function space. If anyone has strong opinions feel free to edit.